# XDocument - Expression help

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to get familiar with using the `XDocument` API to parse XML using the lambda syntax.

What I would like to do is create a `IEnumerable` list of `Product` based on the following XML structure. I know how to get all of the `product` nodes but I want to get each of the product nodes `name` attribute and then select each `item` node from within the 'product' node and parse it for its values.

So I want to take this XML:

```
<products>
  <product name="Prod1">
    <item hwid="abk9184">
      <href>Prod1/abk9184_en-us/abk9184.html</href>
      <localization>en-us</localization>
      <build.start>2011-06-08 22:02 PM</build.start>
      <build.icp>9.0.192.32</build.icp>
    </item>
    <item hwid="abk9185">
      <href>Prod1/abk9185_en-us/abk9185.html</href>
      <localization>en-us</localization>
      <build.start>2011-06-08 22:03 PM</build.start>
      <build.icp>9.0.192.32</build.icp>
    </item>
  </product>
  <product name="Prod2">
    <item hwid="aa6410">
      <href>Prod2/aa6410_en-us/aa6410.html</href>
      <localization>en-us</localization>
      <build.start>2011-06-08 22:04 PM</build.start>
      <build.icp>9.0.192.32</build.icp>
    </item>
  </product>
</products>
```

And from it I would like to get a list of these:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Hwid { get; set; }
    public string Href { get; set; }
    public string Localization { get; set; }
    public DateTime BuildDateTime { get; set; }
    public string IcpBuildVersion { get; set; }
}
```

So although I have 2 product nodes I would end up with many product instances of each. I'd like to learn how to do this using the `XDocument` and the lambda syntax. Can someone show me the way?

```
IEnumerable<Product> products = xDocument.Decendants("product")
                                .Select(e => new Product { Name = e.Name })
```

But think there would have to be some looping here to get each item from each product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var products = document.Descendants("item")
    .Select(arg => 
        new Product
        {
            Name = arg.Parent.Attribute("name").Value,
            Hwid = arg.Attribute("hwid").Value,
            Href = arg.Element("href").Value,
            Localization = arg.Element("localization").Value,
            BuildDateTime = DateTime.Parse(arg.Element("build.start").Value),
            IcpBuildVersion = arg.Element("build.icp").Value
        })
    .ToList();
```